# Use data accross all components

Tags: json, reactjs, api

Created a component where I call all my api's. How do I use that data across all my other components

```
  export let resultData = axios
        .get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/1`)  //used a dummy api to test
        .then(({ data }) => data);
    
    export default class CacheService {
        static myInstance = null;
    
        result = resultData;
    
        static getInstance() {
            if (CacheService.myInstance == null) {
                CacheService.myInstance = new CacheService();
            }
            return this.myInstance;
        }
        findAll() {
            console.log(this.result);
            return this.result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a promise and assigned to `resultData`  variable but its not actually resolved.
Either you can use `await` or use `then` to get the data.

```
let testData = await newData.findAll();

   or 

newData.findAll().then((data)=>{
    testData = data;
});
```

Comment: just a question Im using the second option

Comment: should testData just be let testData = ' ',

Comment: and how would I export testData

Comment: you need to write your login inside then

```newData.findAll().then((data)=>{
    // logic
});
```
else if you want to use this data somewhere else then you need to use the `Await` way

`let testData = await newData.findAll();`
// Your logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to await for the axios to resolve.

```
async findAll() {
    const actualResult = await this.result;
    console.log(actualResult);
    return actualResult;
}
```